# Date to milliseconds in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm making an api with nifi. When I entered the url I had to put start date and end date:

> url / lookup? Start = 2019-05-05 19: 45 & end = 2019-06-06 20:00

Those two dates are saved in the following parameters

> $ {http.param.start}

and

> $ {http.param.end}

How can I pass these parameters to milliseconds? According to several examples that I saw using the: toNumber () but when doing

> $ {http.param.start: toNumber ()}

or

> $ {http.param.end: toNumber ()}

they always arrive empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first - you have to convert string [to date](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#todate) and then date [to number](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#tonumber)

so, expression will be like this:

```
${http.param.start:toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'):toNumber()}
```

Comment: Please edit: params by param, I already modify it in the question. (http.param.start)